# How can I avoid speeding?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I don't have any experience driving in real life, and I'm not from the country the game's setting is.

I just want to know how can I avoid getting that 'speeding' because I only know driving from NFS series, not this game.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is pay attention to the speed limits on the road signs at the side of the road. The signs are round with red edges and a number in the middle. Once you know the speed limit, just keep your truck's speed under the limit by checking the speed-o-meter or top-left corner of the navigator.

[image: Speed Limit 90]

[image: Speed-o-meter]

While driving in the UK, these numbers will be miles per hour, otherwise they are kilometres per hour. In towns the limit is 50 km/h (or 30 mph in the UK). Outside of towns it's usually between 50 and 110 km/h. You will not get a speeding ticket for driving 1-4 km/h too fast.

Another thing to note is that you can't get a speeding ticket for driving too fast unless a traffic camera or one of the patrolling police cars catch you doing it. You can usually see warning signs about such cameras right before them so you know to slow down. The warning sign always includes the camera icon like in the image below.

[image: Speed cameras]

**Update:** The game now also shows a speed limit in the bottom corner of the navigator. This one can be lower than the signs by the road, but traffic cameras go by the signs, not the navigator.

Comment: Exactly how its done on the roads.

Comment: What do those warning signs look like? I've never noticed them.

Comment: Is it me or it's just that 'those' signs you mentioned are so small?

I'm using the (1) view and I don't notice the road signs, and some are just blank, like triangles with red borders.

Comment: @Randomizer do you use a low resolution? I can see them adequately. They can seem small at times when driving fast.

Comment: Cleaned up some comments that got rather off-topic from the game at hand.

Comment: The speed limit is also on the navigator in the bottom left corner, and it often doesn't match the signs.

Comment: Might be noteworthy to add that it's not just speed cameras that will catch you. If there's a nearby police vehicle, it will flash it's blue lights for a second or two and fine you just like a camera would.

Comment: @Mast police cars weren't a thing back then, but added to the answer. Thanks!